# Create dictionary with data per file

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a task where I want to plot several plots in matplotlib. Each plot's date is stored in a single file. To handle it better and directly associate things like filepath and leged entry, I want to create a dictionary with the data of each file:

```
file1 { 'filepath': path/to/file , 'x_data': x[], 'y_data': y[], 'y_legend': 'some_string'}
```

I have a list of all the input files:

```
input_files[file1, file2, ..., file_n]
```

so now I would iterate over the list to create a dictionary for each file. This is the step I am not sure how to do. Any ideas?

```
for i in input_files:
#create dictionary -- how?

   with open (file1):
       fill_dictionary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in input_files:
my_dict = dict()

   with open (file1):
       my_dict=fill_dictionary()
```

I would recommend you to store the data in json files. Then you can read in those files as dictionary

```
import json

with open('path_to_file/data.json', 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

`data` is a dictionary

Comment: Would that not overwrite the same dictionary with the new data everytime I fill the dictionary or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @mr_harm every time you use data = json.load(f), data will be overwritten. But how often you want to load it? If you save the dict before loading it, it will not be overwritten

Comment: I think I was indeed thinking wrong. If I create a list of dictionaries and then iterate over the input list, using the same index for the data list (of dicitionaries, I create a new dictionary for each file. I was hung up on how to iterate the name of each dictionary, which I do not need to like this.

Thanks for the input! I am not sure how to use the jsons though since this would mean creating a file for each file I am parsing, albeit a bit more structured.

Comment: ...even easier: append the dictionary to the list.  `data.append( "dict")`